# How to stop message subscribe using NFC in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-8, nfc

I have Four pages in my application. First page was the log in page here I no use any NFC read or write. And then second page I use both read and write actions of NFC.

Finally I close second page and navigate to the first page.

And I use NFC card in first page it reads the NFC card and display the contents of NFC Card.But I don't wrote any code for NFC actions in this first page and I also use the `stopsubscribemessage()`, but it's not working.

```cs
  private void StopSubscribeMessage()
    {
        MessageBox.Show(subscribedMessageId.ToString());
        if (subscribedMessageId != -1 && new_device != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(subscribedMessageId.ToString()+"   I am a stop method");
            new_device.StopSubscribingForMessage(subscribedMessageId);
            subscribedMessageId = -1;
        }
    }
```